# PostgreSQL doesnt work after Brew update

Tags: macos, postgresql, homebrew

When i try to run `psql` or run `rails s` i am getting the following error

```
➜  ~  psql
psql: could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

**rails s**

```
rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.5.2 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2016-03-02 12:25:29] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2016-03-02 12:25:29] INFO  ruby 2.2.2 (2015-04-13) [x86_64-darwin14]
[2016-03-02 12:25:29] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=12040 port=3000


Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2016-03-02 12:25:38 +0530

PG::ConnectionBad (could not connect to server: No such file or directory
    Is the server running locally and accepting
    connections on Unix domain socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
):
  activerecord (4.2.5.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `initialize'
  activerecord (4.2.5.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `new'
  activerecord (4.2.5.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:651:in `connect'
  activerecord (4.2.5.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:242:in `initialize'
  activerecord (4.2.5.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `new'
  activerecord (4.2.5.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:44:in `postgresql_connection'
  activerecord (4.2.5.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:438:in `new_connection'
  activerecord (4.2.5.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:448:in `checkout_new_connection'
  activerecord (4.2.5.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:422:in `acquire_connection'
  activerecord (4.2.5.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:349:in `block in checkout'
  /Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
  activerecord (4.2.5.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:348:in `checkout'
  activerecord (4.2.5.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:263:in `block in connection'
  /Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/monitor.rb:211:in `mon_synchronize'
  activerecord (4.2.5.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:262:in `connection'
  activerecord (4.2.5.2) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:571:in `retrieve_connection'
  activerecord (4.2.5.2) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:113:in `retrieve_connection'
  activerecord (4.2.5.2) lib/active_record/connection_handling.rb:87:in `connection'
  activerecord (4.2.5.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:383:in `connection'
  activerecord (4.2.5.2) lib/active_record/migration.rb:370:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.5.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `__run_callbacks__'
  activesupport (4.2.5.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:778:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (4.2.5.2) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (4.2.5.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `catch'
  web-console (2.3.0) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:18:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
  railties (4.2.5.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
  railties (4.2.5.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
  activesupport (4.2.5.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.5.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
  activesupport (4.2.5.2) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
  railties (4.2.5.2) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
  activesupport (4.2.5.2) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  actionpack (4.2.5.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:116:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
  railties (4.2.5.2) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
  railties (4.2.5.2) lib/rails/application.rb:165:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
  rack (1.6.4) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:88:in `service'
  /Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
  /Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
  /Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/2.2.0/webrick/server.rb:294:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered /Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_source.erb (2.8ms)
  Rendered /Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.html.erb (1.5ms)
  Rendered /Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.html.erb (0.7ms)
  Rendered /Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/actionpack-4.2.5.2/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.html.erb within rescues/layout (60.6ms)
  Rendered /Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_markup.html.erb (0.4ms)
  Rendered /Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_inner_console_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/_prompt_box_markup.html.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/style.css.erb within layouts/inlined_string (0.3ms)
  Rendered /Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/console.js.erb within layouts/javascript (61.7ms)
  Rendered /Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/main.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.4ms)
  Rendered /Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/error_page.js.erb within layouts/javascript (0.4ms)
  Rendered /Users/harshamv/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/web-console-2.3.0/lib/web_console/templates/index.html.erb (133.3ms)
```

Comment: Is your server started? Have you updated server from one major version to another (from 9.4 to 9.5 for example)? If so then you should use [pg_upgrade](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgupgrade.html) command to migrate your data to newer version.

Comment: @IldarMusin its a new app. yes i think brew updated it to the lastest version of the pg. looks like its the socket problem :(